# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in angular2 for using index in datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have Date input field, if i click on add it gives me same field below the previous one. Now i wrote my HTML like this so it gives the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` and page doesnt open only.. Can any one help me to solve this issue.

HTML:

```
<md-card *ngFor="let positionDetails of positions; let i = index">
<div>
<md-input-container>
   <input mdInput type="text" name="positionDetails.position_start[i]" [ngModel]="positionDetails.position_start [i]| date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" (ngModelChange)="positionDetails.position_start[i] = $event" (focus)="openPosition()[i]" [readonly]="true">
   </md-input-container>
    <div *ngIf="showPosition">
        <datepicker [(ngModel)]="positionstart" name="positionDetails.ddv[i]" [showWeeks]="false" [maxDate]="positionend" (selectionDone)="onPositionStart($event)"></datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
</md-card>
```

Ts:

```
this.positions = [{
      "position_start":"",
    }];
    openPosition(i){
      this.showPosition = true;
    }

    onPositionStart(event:any,i) {
      console.log(event);
      this.positionstart = event;
      console.log(this.positionstart);
      this.positionDetails.position_start = new Date(this.positionstart);
      console.log(this.positionDetails.position_start);
      this.showPosition = false;
    }
```

Comment: you are trying to access `ddv` in your datepicker `name="positionDetails.ddv[i]"`, but you do not have ddv in positions `this.positions = [{ "position_start":"" }];`. Also, are you sure you want to access the i property so much in your html? For example `positionDetails.position_start[i]` is referencing the i index of position_start, not of positionDetails. Do you not mean just `positionDetails.position_start`

Comment: Thanks for response, i have add "ddv" to positions array, the error remains the same. and before it was positionDetails.position_start only.. if i dont add positionDetails.position_start[i], then the page opens.. I am not getting how to solve this issue. Please help. If the page opens also the date selected is displaying on console but not on page.

Comment: So if you remove the `[i]` references everything loads, but the issue now is your datepicker does not display? The datepicker does not display because of your `ngIf` directive. The datepicker only renders when showPosition is true (in your case, after the user focuses the input)

Comment: ya, before instead of positionDetails in ngIf i had used only positions,that time it was working fine, but that was reflecting to all fields when i add new form and enter data. so i used positionDetails. I am not getting how to solve. Now i removed [i], in positionDetails.position_start[i], so i get an error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined as soon as i click on date field

Comment: Sorry, I am confused on what the problem is. What should the code be doing?

Comment: is the way i wrote code is wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160052/discussion-between-llai-and-bhrungarajni).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the scoped `positionDetails` in your ngFor. This will ensure that each iteration of ngFor is separate from one another.

```
<md-card *ngFor="let positionDetails of positions">
  <div>
    <md-input-container>
      <input mdInput type="text" [ngModel]="positionDetails.position_start | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" (focus)="openPosition(positionDetails)" [readonly]="true">
    </md-input-container>
    <div *ngIf="positionDetails.showPosition">
      <datepicker [(ngModel)]="positionDetails.position_start" [showWeeks]="false" [maxDate]="positionend" (selectionDone)="onPositionStart($event, positionDetails)"></datepicker>
    </div>
  </div>
</md-card>
```

This means you'll have to update your methods to only modify the given `positionDetails`

```
openPosition(positionDetails){
  positionDetails.showPosition = true;
}

onPositionStart(event: any, positionDetails) {
  positionDetails.position_start = new Date(event);
  positionDetails.showPosition = false;
}
```

and also give each iteration it's own set of variables

```
this.positions = [{
  "position_start": "",
  "showPosition": false
}];
```